# Is it possible to store a record in a ListBox's Item.Object property?

Tags: delphi, listbox, listboxitem

I have a Record that I would like to store for each Item that add to a Listbox.  Would I need to make the record a class instead to accomplish this?

```
TServerRec = record
    ID: integer;
    DisplayName: string;
    Address: string;
    Port: integer;
end;

procedure TMainForm.PopuplateServers;
var
  server: TServerRec;
begin
  for server in FServerList do
  begin
    lbServers.AddObject(server.DisplayName, server);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but you could store a pointer to this record with a bit of typecasting.  But then you're getting into dynamic record pointer allocation, which can be a bit of a headache.  Why not make TServerRec into an object?

Comment: No real reason, I guess I'll go the Object route.  I just wasn't sure if I was missing something with a record. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 6):

try declarating you structure like this

```
type    
PServerRec = ^TServerRec;
TServerRec = record
    ID: integer;
    DisplayName: string[255];
    Address: string[255];
    Port: integer;
end;

   //now filling your list of objects
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    const
      Max=10;
    var
      FServerList : Array [1..Max] of PServerRec;
      server      : PServerRec;
      i           : Integer;
    begin
      for i := 1 to Max do
      begin
        new(server);
        server^.DisplayName:='Server '+IntToStr(i);
        FServerList[i]:=server;
      end;

      for server in FServerList do
      begin
        lbServers.Items.AddObject(server.DisplayName, TObject(server));
      end;
    end;

    //now to retrieve the info
    procedure TForm1.lbServersDblClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
       server      : TServerRec;
    begin
       server:=PServerRec(lbServers.Items.Objects[lbServers.ItemIndex])^;
       ShowMessage(server.DisplayName);
    end;
```

don't forget to call the  `dispose` function to free the memory of each object allocated.

Comment: Thanks for the input RRUZ, I just went ahead and made TServerRec an Object instead.  Wasn't much work to do and probably really should of been one in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Been there, done that. I solved a similar problem by deriving a new class from the TListbox class, which included a dynamic array of the records that I wanted to keep linked. You will need to override several of the TListbox methods to keep the dynamic array synchronized with the items witin the listbox but it has a few advantages. For example, a dynamic array of record doesn't need to allocate or de-allocate memory. You just need to set the length of the array equal to the number of items in your list. (`SetLength`) You're not accessing records through pointers but through an index. You can just copy records from one location to another in the list, to re-order them.
The drawback? It's a lot of functionality that needs to be overridden and it's not easy to check for bugs in your code, since it needs to work in runtime and design-time. Also be aware that you use records, not classes. If you use classes instead, then you still need to free each element in the array. But records are a lot less complex.